# Javascript Function - Return Response

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am new to javascript and trying to run a javascript function and return a response for this website below.
I am trying to use 'document.querySelectorAll' to return a response for all the job titles and the URL for each job posting.
How do I return a response for these elements?

Website:  https://mckesson.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/External_Careers

Here is my latest attempt:

```js
function ExecuteScript() {
 let nameList = [];
 let response = '';

 document.querySelectorAll('a[data-automation-id="jobTitle"]').forEach((element, i) => {
  nameList.push(element.innerHTML);

 document.querySelectorAll('a[data-automation-id="jobTitle"]').forEach((element, i) => {
  response += nameList[i] + '\\t' + element.getAttribute('hef') + '\\n';
 });

 return response;
}
```

Comment: You should probably fix your syntax errors and provide an [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the example code:

1. Syntax error: Two `querySelectorAll` are not nested correctly.
2. Misspellings: `hef` should be `href`, and it's not enough to store only relative addresses; you need to add domain names in front of them.
3. Because both capture elements of the same class, the two loops can be merged.

Can refer to the following code:

```
function ExecuteScript() {
  let response = '';
  document.querySelectorAll('a[data-automation-id="jobTitle"]').forEach((element, i) => {
    response += element.innerHTML + '\\t' + location.host + element.getAttribute('href') + '\\n';
  });
  return response;
}
```

Comment: @tdy I'm terribly sorry. I tried to add some suggestions and principles

Comment: This response helped me scrape the website I put in my initial question. I was using Microsoft Power Automate Desktop to scrape the website in my initial question and used the 'Run Javascript function on webpage' action in Microsoft Power Automate Desktop to execute a javascript function to scrape by css selector. This javacsript function gave me the response I needed to scrape each job posting and the job posting's URL. Thank you so much @lie! Please let me know if I need to add more info in my initial question so readers better understand the solution.

Comment: @lie no need to apologize! good explanations, upvoted

Comment: @lie what if I was trying to capture another element that was not in the same class, how would I create 2 separate loops?